# Delphi Excel OLE Chart data labels issue

Tags: excel, vba, delphi, ole

I want to automate the generating of a chart having the labels of form "text + percentage" but I want to have the text on a row and the percentage bellow it (on the next row).
I use this function to generate the chart's labels:

```
E.ActiveChart.ApplyDataLabels(xlDataLabelsShowLabelAndPercent, false,true,
                              true, false, true, true,false, false,'; ');
```

This function generates the labels separated by a semicolon. So I basically want to be able to replace the '; ' with something that says (New Line) ?!?!
or better yet, after checking out the VBA I noticed that internally it is coded as 
" & Chr(10) & "
But I do not have the desired result if I use this coding in my function.
So my end result needs to be something like this:
[image]

What should I send in my ApplyDataLabels function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chr(10) has been generally used by windows to insert line breaks in text being displayed to windows controls.

If it has to be constructed as a string it might have to be specified this way:

```
E.ActiveChart.ApplyDataLabels(xlDataLabelsShowLabelAndPercent, false,true,
                              true, false, true, true,false, false, AnsiString(#10));
```

Comment: I tried the first one myself before seing your answer and it did not work. However the second way works fine. Thank you for your time +1

Comment: I have edited my answer. I don't use Delphi so the first version I was unsure if it would be smart enough to change a Chr to a Variant (to be passed to ApplyDataLabels) so I added the second example. Thanks for the feedback